# Value does not fall within expected range error Sharepoint 2013 CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I use a caml query to check whether a file exits in a given folder. When I run the application it gives an error saying "Value does not fall within expected range". What am I doing wrong. I have added the code below. 
Thanks in advance.

```
string Librery = "Scans";
string folder = @"/"+Librery+"/"+textBox1.Text.Trim();
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://test/sites/LegalDocs");
newFile.Url = "Pens.docx";

 if (!FileExists(clientContext, Librery, newFile.Url, folder))
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = ii.Files.Add(newFile);
                    clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

public bool FileExists(ClientContext clientContext, String list, String fileName, String relativeDir)
    {
        List DocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                <Query>
                                    <Where>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'></FieldRef>
                                            <Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + @"</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                    </Where>
                                </Query>
                        </View>";
        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = relativeDir; ;
        ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return listItems.Count > 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the corresponding error in the *ULS* logs, you see something like this:

```
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItems. Exception=System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(String strUrl, Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.Init(SPList list, SPQuery query, String strViewName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItems(SPQuery query)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
```

The `FolderServerRelativeUrl` means server relative, not site relative. In your case it means:

```
string folder = @"/sites/LegalDocs/"+Librery+"/"+textBox1.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: It worked for me.